# How to add linkedin auth to nextjs supabase project

Tags: oauth, next-auth, supabase

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/supabase-authenticate-users-with-github-oauth-using-supabase-and-next-js-client-components).

I am trying to add LinkedIn oauth instead of github. I have seen [this documentation](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/social-login/auth-linkedin) and have been attempting to follow its instructions.

I have a sign in component with:

'use client'
import { createClientComponentClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";

```
export default function AuthButton() {
    const supabase = createClientComponentClient();
    
    const handleSignIn = async () => {
        await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
            provider: 'linkedin',
            // options: {
            //     redirectTo: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/callback'
            // }
        }); // <-- Added closing parenthesis
    };
     
    return (
        <button onClick={handleSignIn}>Sign in</button>
    );
}
```

In my .env file, I have saved both the secret and client ids. I have also added both of them to my supabase provider file.

When I try to run this, and click the sign in button, I get a linkedin page that says:

> > Bummer, something went wrong. In five seconds, you will be redirected to: thisstringisthecallbackfromsupabase.supabase.co

How can i figure out how to debug this error?

In the console, whilst the error page is loaded, I can see these errors:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined Uncaught Error:
> TrackingTwo requires an initialPageInstance POST
> https://api.linkedin.com/li/track 404 (Not Found)

I am certain that I have correctly copied and pasted the id and secret keys from linkedin to supabase.

I signed up to a propeller auth account to try and see if i could get linkedin oauth to work through that service. It generates an error message that says:

> Query deserialize error: missing field `code`

Does anyone know how to get linkedin outh to work - either natively or through one of the user management platforms?

Answer (score 0):

To add LinkedIn authentication to your Next.js Supabase project, you need to create a LinkedIn OAuth application and add the application credentials to your Supabase dashboard.

Here are the steps you can follow:

- Create a LinkedIn project and app on the LinkedIn Developer
  Dashboard.

  https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/social-login/auth-linkedin
- Retrieve your project’s URL and anon key from your API settings, and create
  a `.env.local` file with the following environment variables:

  ```
  NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL=your-supabase-url
  NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY=your-supabase-anon-key
  ```
- Install the Next.js Auth Helpers library by running the following command:

  ```
  npm install @supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs @supabase/supabase-js
  ```
- Add the LinkedIn login code to your Supabase JS client app by following the
  instructions in the link:

  https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/social-login/auth-linkedin
- Use middleware to refresh the user’s session before loading Server Component
  routes. You can follow the given link:

  https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs

Comment: did you read the post?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is stuck on these linkedin JS errors, I noticed they put the specific error in the redirect_uri. Mine showed like so: redirect?error=unsupported_response_type&error_description=We+only+support+a+response_type+of+"code"+but+you+passed+"token"

Using "token" is the Implicit Grant flow which exposes the token directly in the browser or mobile app. Using "code" is the Authorization Code flow and is more secure.

Once I changed it to "code" it stopped showing the "Bummer, something went wrong. In five seconds, you will be redirected to" error and showed the linkedin login screen.